# How do you say in English that something is "genuinely good regardless of its disadvantages"?

Tags: phrases, comparisons

I'm writing about a certain product. I want to describe all its shortcomings but then move on to make the point that it is still good, and I can't find a word. Google and Ludwig Guru translated it: 'overweight something', but that doesn't sound right.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with “genuinely good regardless of its disadvantages”? That phrase sounds fine to me.

Comment: It is not wrong but too long and sounds robotic

Comment: 'Its advantages outweigh its disadvantages' is perhaps what the translator was aiming at.

Comment: I'd say, *Despite its shortcomings, on the balance it's a good product.

Comment: I would say "On the whole, it's a good product."